# I'm getting an error trying to paste special unformatted when charts are present - and I don't want the charts

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy

This portion of code only fails if a chart or other object (like a PowerPoint shape) is on the sheet being copied from. But why does that matter? We're only pasting values, column widths, and formats. Is there a way to say **copy everything except charts and other objects**?

wb1 is the current workbook - wsNew is a new sheet in the wb2 (new) workbook:

```
wb1.Sheets(x).Range("Print_Area").Copy
Set wsNew = wb2.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
wsNew.Activate
wsNew.Select
With Selection
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  .MergeCells = False
End With
```

Comment: You're selecting the whole worksheet. Loop through and select the columns and data you want

Comment: Nope. Still fails. The range with the chart fails - even if I try to just paste only that range - it fails. Defined rNew as the new range to match the existing print area range - but it still fails. Works on sheets without charts, no problem.

Comment: You can set the value of `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells` to not copy objects when copying a range.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.copyobjectswithcells

Comment: How does it fail?  What's the error you get and on which line?

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams - I thought that would fix it - but I still get the error on the Copy line. Even if I put the Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False immediately before it. I had it earlier, certain that was the fix, but that didn't work. I moved it closer - still doesn't work.

Comment: (And yes, there's a print area defined on each sheet. I triple checked.)

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error. Always at this line of code:

wb1.sheets(x).Range.("Print_Area").Copy

Comment: Good news! I woke up this morning with the intuition that maybe since the macro file had crashed recently, there was corruption and that was the issue, not the code. Sure enough, I cut the code from Excel, pasted to Notebook, Saved and reopened the excel file, copied and pasted from Notebook (to clean it of any hidden strangeness) and boom, it worked. So this question has been answered - and I suspect it was the application.CopyObjectsWithCells that fixed it.